# android how I can run a function after the ui has been drawn?

Tags: android

I thought my `UI` would be ready in `onResume` method.
However, my application crashed when I run:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.a, b).commit();
```

right after `super.onResume()`, and the screen was white when it crashed.

Where should I run this code, so that it won't give:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You should first get familar with Android the [Android Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

And then improve your Question, if you still have that problem.

A stacktrace would be nice for example.

But first, you should make sure, you know what you're coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onGlobalLayout listener to the main view, which will get called '[when the global layout state or the visibility of views within the view tree changes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html)'. Do something like the snippet below in your `onResume` method:

```
final View mainview = findViewById(R.id.main);
ViewTreeObserver vto = mainview.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
          [your code here]
           ViewTreeObserver obs = mainview.getViewTreeObserver();
          obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
}
```

The last bit is to avoid getting a callback every time the layout changes.

Comment: I got null pointer exception on ` ViewTreeObserver obs = mainview.getViewTreeObserver();` . If I put my code in onCreateOptionsMenu it will work. but I don't want my app to have an action bar. is there similar place to put my code?